# ssh tunnelling port forwarding

Tags: ssh

I have three computers, A, B, C. A is the computer I'm working on, C is the remote computer I'd like to access. However C can only be accessed through B. Only B has a ssh server, and only A has a ssh client.

What command am I to use (preferably on A) so that I can connect to C (port 80) through B ? For example B should forward all incoming port 12345 to C:80.

I know this is a common question and I found a ton of commands on google but none seemed to work.

Once it is set up, I'm supposed to just use localhost:5678 on A, which connects to B:1234, and then forwards to C:80.

Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/107679/1845

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think this answers my question. The link you mentioned offers to connect from A to C with ssh, whereas I want to access a web server on C. I know the difference is not huge, but I'm failing to find the correct way to adapt to my issue.

Comment: Oh, then it's a trivial forward.  On A, run `ssh -L5678:C:80 B`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use remote port forward:

From A run
    ssh -R *:1234:C:80  you@B

Then you can access C by typing B:1234, but this also requires setting GatewayPorts to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config , and the restart sshd (this tells C to listen to all IP addresses, not just local IPs, so it can be accessed from the outside)

Once you logout from B, it will also disable the tunnel to C.

Comment: It takes time to get used to `ssh forwarding`. Because you used `-R`, the server `C` is now in the context of A's LAN network and this is not what the question is all about so `-R` is wrong here. SSH port forwarding is useful and **best understood** when the `ssh client` and the `ssh server` belongs to two different LAN networks. If **-L**, this context is from the `ssh server's` LAN network.  If **-R**, this context is from the `ssh client's` LAN network. Imagine, there could be similar ip address of `C` between these two LAN networks.